# How to Change Amazon S3 file URL Like s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key from bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key in Java?

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, endpoint

Working with AmazonS3 bucket - After uploading file to bucket, we can get uploaded file URL using below code :

```
String fileDownloadUrl = AmzonS3Client.getUrl(bucketName, fileName);
```

In Result it will give url like i.e : bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key but I want s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key. So Can anyone help me how can I solve this in java?

Answer (score 1):

By default pathstyleaccess is false so your uploaded file should be bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key but when you explicitly add clientOptions -- pathStyleAccess to true then it will generate URL like s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key. Please find below code snippet

S3ClientOptions clientOptions = new S3ClientOptions();
clientOptions.setPathStyleAccess(true);

And set this clientOptions to Amazons3client.

Comment: .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

Create `AmazonS3Client` object using `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` with `enablePathStyleAccess()`.

```
AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .enablePathStyleAccess()
        .withRegion(regionName)
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .build();
```